# upload image to mysql database php

Tags: php, mysql, database, image

i want to upload an image to php database, my php code

```
<?php
session_start();
include('../../includes/connect.php');

$title = $_POST['title'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$file = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']));
$image_size = getimagesize($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
$visiable = 1;

$query = "insert into news (title, subject, image, visiable) values ('$title','$subject', '$image', '$visiable')"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$id = mysql_insert_id();

$data = array(
        'id' => $id
        );
$base = '../../show.php';
$url = $base. '?' . http_build_query($data);
header("Location: $url");
exit();?>
```

but it upload nothing the image field is still 0 byte, it works me yesterday but today i dont know what happened, I hop that someone can help me, sorry for my bad english

Comment: *"but it upload nothing"* where is your `move_uploaded_files` function?

Comment: it works with me yesterday without move_uploaded_files

Comment: Before you write **any** more SQL code, you absolutely must read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid the sorts of [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) you're probably experiencing here. You should also **not** be using `mysql_query` in new code, it's a deprecated interface that's being removed from PHP. A modern interface like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). Seeing `addslashes` is usually a sign you're using a massively out of date tutorial.

Comment: @BassamBadr Oh? Do tell, I know of no other way. There is something I obviously am not aware of then.

Comment: @BassamBadr So, if it worked for you yesterday, then why are you asking this question today?

Comment: Do you have permissions to move file to the destination directory?

Comment: @Vikram Apparently he doesn't need to "move" his file(s).

Comment: @Jack it works yesterday but now it doesnt

Comment: @BassamBadr For **"Grammar's"** sake, it's **"visible"**, and not **"visiable"**. *Just saying* (wink)

Comment: @BassamBadr You're saving a record into the database, but where do you actually save the file?

Comment: @tadman in field called image

Comment: @tadman He doesn't need to, it's done without the use of `move_uploaded_files`, apparently or so he/she says. Or is the OP not using the right **"term"** >>> (upload)?

Comment: Please, read up on proper SQL escaping like I said. `addslashes` is not the tool you're supposed to be using, and any files with random binary data will only work by pure chance. I don't know where you learned to do it this way, but it's not the right way.

Comment: Apparently, "I don't know Jack".

Comment: @Fred In this case it's done by slapping a slashified (but not escaped) version of the file into the query string. `move_uploaded_files` is the better method of storing arbitrary binary data since MySQL is not a filesystem. I think some kinds of files will make for very rough queries and won't get inserted correctly. If there's an error it won't be shown since there's zero error handling here. Basically this is an example of why you do not do this by hand and instead [use a popular framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) where this is all done for you.

Comment: @tadman Thanks for the info on that. Call me "Old School", but I'll just stick to `move_uploaded_files` (wink). I'm just wondering why the OP is going through all that extra trouble if it's not efficient. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script I modified to work with your table structure.

```
function addImageToDB($imageArray, $title = '', $subject = '', $visible = 0) {

$allowedExts = array("gif","jpeg","jpg","JPG","png","PNG");
$extension = end(explode(".", $imageArray["name"]));

if (
    (($imageArray["type"] == "image/gif") // is image type acceptable?
        || ($imageArray["type"] == "image/jpeg")
        || ($imageArray["type"] == "image/jpg")
        || ($imageArray["type"] == "image/png")
    )
    && ($imageArray["size"] < 1048576) // set maximum image size
    && in_array($extension, $allowedExts) // is image file extension in $allowedExts?
) {

    if ($imageArray["error"] > 0) { // check uploaded image for errors
        echo $imageArray['error'];
    } else {

        $tempImage = $imageArray['tmp_name'];
        $fp = fopen($tempImage, 'r');
        $image = fread($fp, filesize($tempImage));
        $image = addslashes($image);
        fclose($fp);

        $queryAddImageToDB = "INSERT INTO image (
            title,
            subject,
            image,
            visible
        ) VALUES (
            '$title'
            '$subject',
            '$image',
            '$visible'
        )";

        mysql_query ($queryAddImageToDB) or die ('queryAddImageToDB failed');
        $imageID = mysql_insert_id();

        return $imageID;

    }
} else {

    echo 'IMAGE UPLOAD ERROR: The image ie either too large or the file format is unacceptable.';

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($imageArray); // display image array for debugging
    echo '</pre>';

}
```

}

You can call the function like this:

```
$imageArray = $_FILES['image'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$visible = 1;
addImageToDB($imageArray, $title, $subject, $visible);
```

*Please note that this script IS NOT COMPLETE as it needs proper validation, escaping, etc.*

Good luck I hope this works out for you and I look forward to hearing feedback otherwise.